# Frugal installation on WIN 7 no admin rights

Tags: linux, usb

Laptop from my work has WIN 7 Enterprise, but I have no admin rights on it and under no circumstances I would change partitions. However it does boot from USB. As I want to use Linux on a regular basis while at home, and I need it to be fast and reliable (also on Win 7 side - so Windows won't crash), could you please tell me:

**how to make a frugal installation in a Win 7 folder with booting from USB stick** .

I am aware that one can install full Linux on a USB, but it wears out USB memory and probably is not that fast as system operating on a HDD. I've imagined that only core system components and HDD mounting loads from USB stick, but the rest functions on HDD under Win 7. Is it possible with any distro?

Comment: Use an USB harddisk? With USB3 you'll hardly notice a difference to internal disks. While in theory it would probably be possible to use a large file on an NTFS partition via loopback device in Linux, installing a whole system on it is not trivial at all. You'd probably end up having to boot via USB in order to not mess with the Win installation (and its bootloader), make the initrd aware of NTFS, and somehow get the loopback device set up pretty early on.